# AWS SageMaker Neo fails to compile PyTorch model

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have a PyTorch model that I've saved following [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/neo-compilation-preparing-model.html) into a .tar.gz file I uploaded it to S3, and then tried to compile it using AWS SageMaker neo.

It fails with the error: ClientError: InputConfiguration: Framework cannot load PyTorch model. [enforce fail at inline_container.cc:222] . file not found: neo/version

My target platform is x86_64. Other settings are as in the screenshot.[image]

How do I fix this?